# How to repeat options and/or set a short option for a tool in pyproject.toml

Tags: pyproject.toml

The reason for this question is the following:

`codespell` allows to specify custom dictionaries, but to maintain the use of the main dictionary, the same option needs to be repeated.

```bash
codespell --dictionary - --dictionary dict.txt
```

I tried to repeat the option in `pyproject.toml` but that did not work.

As the shorthand for `--dictionary` is `-D` I thought I could specify two different options, one short and one long:

```ini
[tool.codespell]
D = "-"
dictionary = "dev/tools/codespell/codespell-dict.txt"
```

But that converts into `--D`.

Hence the question(s) regarding the `pyproject.toml` configuration:

how to repeat an option (here: `dictionary`), and/or, how to specify a short option ?